# Calculating $\int \frac{e^{2x}}{1+e^x} \, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Problem:

> Calculate $\displaystyle\int \frac{e^{2x}}{1+e^x} \, dx $.

My book says to divide in order to solve by getting $\displaystyle\int\left(e^x-\frac{e^{x}}{1+e^x}\right)\, dx $ but how am I supposed to divide? I tried long division but the exponents have variables so I don’t think you can use long division (plus my answer from long division didn’t match).

Comment: I think your book is using the term divide colloquially to mean split the integrand into two terms, but by using subtraction rather than long division:  $\dfrac {e^{2x}}{1+e^x} = e^x - \dfrac{e^x}{1+e^x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac {e^{2x}}{e^x+1} = \frac {e^{2x}+e^x-e^x}{e^x+1}=$$

$$\frac {e^{x}(e^x+1)-e^x}{e^x+1}=e^x-\frac {e^x}{e^x+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

To get the result in your book, note that
$$e^{2x}=e^x e^x=e^x(e^x+1-1)=e^x(e^x+1)-e^x$$

Comment: Effectively perform long division on$$\frac{y^2}{1+y}=y-\frac{y}{1+y}$$where $y=e^x$

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes, but I can't do long division in the usual sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Just think of $e^{2x}$ as $(e^x)^2$. Now your integrand takes the form $\frac{u^2}{1+u}$, so you can long divide those polynomials in $u$ as usual.  That's how they got that decomposition.  This does not handle the differential terms as in substitution.  That would have to happen after the algebraic moves.

Comment: (To be clear, $dx = \frac{du}{u}$, so the integrand of the integral in $u$ produced by the substitution is $\frac{u}{1 + u}$.)

Comment: I'm not doing the integral by substitution, I'm just showing how to do the algebra. That was OP's question.

Comment: Yes, I know---I wasn't attempting a correction, I'm sorry for giving the appearance I was. The context of OP's question was in the computation of an integral, so it seems plausible that a reader might (mis)take "your integrand takes the form..." for something like "the integrand in the new variable after carrying out the substitution implicit here is...", and I was aiming to emphasize for such a reader that you meant (literally) the former and not the latter.

Comment: @Travis  that is a fair point.  You are right to clarify:  I'm not accounting for the differential term at all, just handling the algebra.  Will update.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is simpler to first use the substitution
$$u=e^x$$
to obtain the integral of a rational function:
$$\int\dfrac{u}{1+u}\,du$$
and then use division of polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \frac{e^{2x}}{1+e^x}dx=\int \frac{e^{2x}-1+1}{1+e^x}dx\\
\\
=\int \frac{e^{2x}-1}{1+e^x}dx+\int \frac{1}{e^x+1}dx\\
\\
=\int (e^x-1)dx+\int \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}dx\\
\\
=e^x-x-\ln(1+e^{-x})+c$$